# change class on div on click/toggle on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site overlay Div (#site-overlay) that I have set as display:none, and want to change the class to block when I hover and click my menu buttons. I can use both vanilla Javascript and Jquery for this.

My menu is Javascriptbased, so not sure if its enough to toggle the menubutton divs?

This is the html for the buttons in the menu:

```
<ul class="megamenu">
    <li class="megamenu_button" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#_">Mega Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li style="">
        <a href="#_" class="megamenu_drop">Computers</a>
        <div class="dropdown_fullwidth" style="left: -1px; top: auto; display: block;">
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jerryskate/doxdmxmL/

Comment: are you familiar with jquery ?

Comment: Yeah. I use it, but I dont have a good understanding if it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use show() and hide()

Full code with events

```
$('#megamenu_button').mouseover(function(){
  $('#site-overlay').show();
  })
  .mouseout(function(){
     $('#site-overlay').hide();
  });
});
/*and*/
$('#megamenu_button').click($('#site-overlay').toggle());
```

The first Function does that the site-overlay appears when u hover on the button and disappears when u take the mouse off the button

2nd function is kinda self explaining. when u click the button the site overlay disappears or appears

Comment: Should I use  the top part in the code aswell, or would the second part be enough? @zeropublix

Comment: just ignore the topPart. i kinda lost myself in changing from hide to show back to css

Comment: Ok! How would i set the css of the div then? I guess i dont need the display:none of it?

Comment: What css do you mean? the inital CSS when the page loads?If so just leave it as it is. because the above jQuery codes manipulates the Element anyway

Comment: well if the mega-button is never visible. none of the events will ever be called since they just get called when something with the megaButton is done. If possible could u provide a jsfiddle with the html and css to show me WHAT you actually want to do

Comment: The code you provided doesn't seems to work, as shown in the codepen here codepen.io/anon/pen/xbawVM .- Maybe i wrote it wrong? @zeropublix

Comment: because your codepen doesnt include jQuery libary.. my code is based on it

[here is an example jsfiddle where it works](https://jsfiddle.net/cot4nz1g/)

Comment: Ah. Bad example to use codepen then. heres a fiddle with my full code and your script . i cant get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Jerryskate/doxdmxmL/

Comment: great to hear . sorry i couldnt answer you, im doing this support from work

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. The clickevent was a bit harder. What is missing to make it work? now it shows the div as default. Thanks again! http://jsfiddle.net/Jerryskate/doxdmxmL/1/ @zeropublix

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toggleClass()`

> Description: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

```
$("#megamenu_button").togleClass(class, vaulue);
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, I need  to change the class of another div when hover and click the megamenu button. (#site-overlay)

Comment: so you need `toggleClass()`

Answer (score 0):

toggle() should be able to fix your problem

```
$("#megamenu_button").toggle()
```

Comment: How do I target my div with this? @Abuzar Hasan

Comment: you can do that by using the class/id of your target element

Comment: in your case, first <li> has class="megamenu_button". So, you can use $(".megamenu_button").toggle()
use dot "." for class and hash "#" for id
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but still dont understand. when I click megamenu I want to target #site-overlay. here is a codepen of the problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbawVM